# mkdir is not working

Tags: php, directory, mkdir

The `mkdir()` is not working for me. What is going wrong in this code?

```
  foreach($_FILES['documents']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name)
 {
   $file_name = $key.$_FILES['documents']['name'][$key];
   $file_size =$_FILES['documents']['size'][$key];
   $file_tmp =$_FILES['documents']['tmp_name'][$key];
   $file_type=$_FILES['documents']['type'][$key];
   $name = $_POST['uname'][$key];
   $email = $_POST['uemail'][$key];
   $password = $_POST['epass'][$key];
   $file_names = time().$file_name;

   $query = "INSERT INTO `table` VALUES
  ('', '$name', '', '', '$email', '$password', 1, '', 1, '', '$file_names',   '$file_names', '', '', '', '', 1, '', '', '1', '')";

   $resultl =  $db->insert($query);

   $userId = mysql_insert_id();

   $output_dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."uploads/users/$userId/";
   mkdir($output_dir, 0777);
   chmod($output_dir, 0777);
```

The directory is not being created. I searched in Stack Overflow for the solution and applied some of them  but still no success. I am using `wamp`; when I move the uploaded image without creating directory, then it moves the file.

Comment: Print the value of  `$output_dir` before executing the mkdir.  Check that the webserver has the permission to make a new directory there.

Comment: i have echoed the $output_dir that is also correct , i am trying this from last four hours still unable to get what wrong i am doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$output_dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/uploads/users/$userId/";

mkdir($output_dir, 0777, true);
```

Answer (score 3):

The user running your PHP script (most likely `www-data`) should have the permission to create a folder in $output_dir, so you may want to check that it is indeed the case.

What's more, it's generally a bad programming habit to just ignore the return value of a system call. `mkdir` will return FALSE on failure, which you should test against and then make sure your code acts accordingly should the directory creation fail... When `mkdir` fails, it will also log a warning so you should be able to get more information on the actual problem by having a look at your logs (provided you're logging warnings).

Answer (score 1):

```
mkdir('$output_dir' ,0777) ;
chmod('$output_dir',0777);
```

should be

```
mkdir($output_dir ,0777) ;
chmod($output_dir,0777);
```

Comment: you have put recursive on, like `mkdir($output_dir ,0777, true) ;`

Answer (score 1):

Try this and if not working post the msg.

```
  <?php 
    ....
    $output_dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/uploads/users/$userId/";
    echo $output_dir;
    $res =  mkdir($output_dir ,0777, true) ;
    var_dump($res);
```

Comment: permission is not set for uploads folder

Answer (score 1):

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/uploads/users/$userId/";
```

Try adding a directory separator after $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] like above.

Answer (score 0):

Give the appropriate permissions to the `uploads` folder so the `www-data` user can traverse it, and to the `uploads/users` subfolder, with the `write` permission.